# (i) above icon long press options on Pixel XL but not Nexus 6P

Tags: stock-android, 7.1-nougat, 8.0-oreo, 8.1-oreo

Whilst I was still using my Nexus 6P as my main phone, I upgraded to the beta version of Android 7.x (and more recently Android 8.x). When I long press an icon on my home screen, such as Google Maps, I get the list of shortcuts for directions home/work etc. and that is all.

If I do the same on my Pixel XL or Pixel 2 XL running the latest non beta version of Android, above the list of direction shortcuts, I see another row with an 'i' in a circle. Pressing it takes me to the App Info screen for that app.

Why is this only on my pixels and not the 6P and can I turn it off?

Comment: Did you update the launcher on devices it's not showing? AFAIK it's supposed to be same. I don't have any of those devices

Comment: Yes, launcher is up to date